# How to contact the same df with df.iloc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset where if i write df.iloc[0] it'll return a dataset like below

```
     Pincode    Pincode_1 Id        P
0   416525.0    416602    5005162   16.943508
1   416525.0    416520    5005163   25.359940
```

If i write df.iloc[1], it'll return another dataframe with same columns and different rows. Below is the output of df.iloc[1]

```
     Pincode    Pincode_1 Id        P
0   416325.0    416602    5005162   16.943508
1   416425.0    416520    5005163   25.359940
```

I have a shape of 190 rows. I tried using for loop and tried to concat from df.iloc[0] till df.iloc[190], but it's not working.

```
for i in range(0,190):
    pd.concat([df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i]])
```

Below is the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [121], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in range(0,190):
----> 2     pd.concat([df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i]])

File ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:967, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
    964 axis = self.axis or 0
    966 maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 967 return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

File ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1520, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1517     raise TypeError("Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key")
   1519 # validate the location
-> 1520 self._validate_integer(key, axis)
   1522 return self.obj._ixs(key, axis=axis)

File ~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1452, in _iLocIndexer._validate_integer(self, key, axis)
   1450 len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   1451 if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 1452     raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues, not accounting for the error you're getting.
First, iloc only returns one row of data. Since you indicate that it's returning two rows, I suspect that your initial dataframe isn't structured correctly. Do you really have 190 rows, or do you actually have 380?
Second, you are concatenating each item to itself. pd.concat([df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i]]) refers to the same row[i] twice. You probably meant to do something like pd.concat([df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i+1]]), but that won't do what you want either.
Third, pd.concat returns a dataframe, but you're not assigning the dataframe to any variable. So...even though you're trying to iterate over everything, you aren't saving the output anywhere.